# JAXB Unmarshalling: Sporadic Null Pointer Exception

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, unmarshalling

I have been trying to unmarshal an xml which succeeds regularly but fails with Null Pointer Exception sporadically. The exception trace is below:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.Coordinator.pushCoordinator(Coordinator.java:149)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:501)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.endElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:77)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:156)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:276)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:245)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:122)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:314)
            at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:297)
```

Could anyone help to understand under what circumstances does this exception occur?

**Java version: OpenJDK 1.8u151**

#### XML:

```
<model-templates version="v3" selectList="system,system-info,interfaces,services,config,state,dummy-types,dummy-interfaces-ip,dummy-interfaces-tunnel,dummy-interfaces-aggr,dummy-interfaces-common,dummy-interfaces-vport,dummy-interfaces-attachment-circuit,dummy-Unmarshalled" schemaList="org/example/my/tree/v3-api/{{version}}/v3-api-{{version}}.jar,org/example/my/tree/v3-dummy-model/{{version}}/v3-dummy-model-{{version}}.jar,org/example/my/tree/baseservice-api/{{version}}/baseservice-api-{{version}}.jar,org/example/my/tree/common-models/{{version}}/common-models-{{version}}.jar,org/opendaylight/mdsal/model/ext/2013.09.07.9.3-Boron-SR3/ext-2013.09.07.9.3-Boron-SR3.jar,org/opendaylight/mdsal/model/ietf-topology/2013.10.21.9.3-Boron-SR3/ietf-topology-2013.10.21.9.3-Boron-SR3.jar,org/opendaylight/mdsal/model/ietf-interfaces/2014.05.08.9.3-Boron-SR3/ietf-interfaces-2014.05.08.9.3-Boron-SR3.jar,org/opendaylight/mdsal/model/ietf-inet-types-2013-07-15/1.1.3-Boron-SR3/ietf-inet-types-2013-07-15-1.1.3-Boron-SR3.jar,org/opendaylight/mdsal/model/ietf-types-20130715/2013.07.15.9.3-Boron-SR3/ietf-types-20130715-2013.07.15.9.3-Boron-SR3.jar,org/opendaylight/mdsal/model/ietf-types/2010.09.24.9.3-Boron-SR3/ietf-types-2010.09.24.9.3-Boron-SR3.jar,org/opendaylight/netconf/ietf-netconf/1.1.3-Boron-SR3/ietf-netconf-1.1.3-Boron-SR3.jar,org/opendaylight/mdsal/model/iana-if-type-2014-05-08/2014.05.08.9.3-Boron-SR3/iana-if-type-2014-05-08-2014.05.08.9.3-Boron-SR3.jar">
    <template id="dummy-system" namespace="http://www.example.com/ns/dummy-system" revision="2018-11-07"/>
</model-templates>
```

Comment: Can you provide the code which you use to unmarshal? I'm lazy to google com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl + you might have types something incorrectly, never hurts to check